# Ajax Load - Change pages HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, socket.io, load

Is it possible to change the whole HTML with ajax $.load?

```
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#mainContainer').html('Loading');
    },
    complete: function(){
      $('body').remove();
      $('head').remove();
    },
    success: function(data){
       $('html').append(data);
    }
});
```

I have tried this code, but the scripts (socket.io, game.js etc) does not work well together with the load function. The page works 100% when I visit directly, but not through $.load. Also the CSS does not load correctly, and is being corrupted by the original pages CSS.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the problem you have is that the `<script>` tags you insert dynamically by text with `$('html').append` are not evaluated.

If you want scripts to be loaded when added to the DOM, you will need to explicitly create the nodes. For instance,

```js
$('<script>')
  .attr('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.1/socket.io.js')
  .appendTo('head');
```

should properly load the library.

Integrating this with your AJAX setup may be difficult. There are hacky solutions that will work in some cases, but you are better off structuring the application differently.